# Mouse jumps around when using DOSBOX

Tags: technical-issues, mouse, dosbox

I'm trying to play an old school DOS Game I got using the DOSBOX DOS emulator, but the problem I have is that the mouse jumps all over the screen and does not allow me to have a good control. The game is Cannon Fodder, which need to have mouse input. So I'm thinking it is problem of conversion from USB mouse to the serial driver which the emulator uses. I already tried to lower the sensitivity using the emulator and to lower it using windows settings.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: DId a little research on this. Have you tried a PS/2 mouse, or can you do that?

Comment: only have usb input

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not 100% sure this is the problem, but `autolock` often causes mouse issues in DOSBox. So try setting it to the opposite of whatever it currently is:

- In your `dosbox.conf` file, look for a line setting `autolock=false` and remove the line (or change the `false` to `true`).
- Or, if no line with `autolock` exists, add one with `autolock=false`.

Comment: i was able to fix it looks like game created it own config file called. dosboxCannonFodder.conf so i had to modify that file. 
i set sensitivity=1

Comment: Setting autolock to false solved my issues with mouse in Dosbox. If you still need the mouse locked to the window (eg when playing shooter games), you can press Ctrl+F10 to manually lock the mouse to the window (works for me) or switch to full screen.

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to run dosbox in a virtualbox Ubuntu host, I had the same issue and it was driving me crazy. The mouse would just get stuck in a corner and wouldn't move except to the other corners. [Here's the solution I found](http://lovehateubuntu.blogspot.ca/2008/04/dosbox-on-ubuntu.html):

Make a text file and put this in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SDL_VIDEO_X11_DGAMOUSE=0
dosbox
```

Save it on your desktop or somewhere else, right click on it and put a check where it say "allow to execute as application". Run the file and the mouse issue will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for my mouse problem with the "Tex Murphy Martian Memorandum" version that comes with GoG.

Answer (score 4):

I know that the original poster has already resolved their issue, but for everyone else hitting this from Google: for me this was an issue with VirtualBox's mouse integration. To fix it, disable your virtual machine's mouse integration by right clicking on the mouse icon in the bottom right-hand corner (second icon from the right).

After this, the mouse should respond to the sensitivity setting in DOSBox.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running Windows 10 who didn't have luck with the existing suggestions, using the DOSBox SVN-Daum menu option "Video/Driver/Restart DOSBox with DirectX Driver Only" worked for me. I've also added autolock=false to the config and turned off scaling, but I'm not sure if they had any effect.